# Query states to get records where time is in the future, query also getting records from past

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query where I'm trying to get all get records from the future. It's also getting records from the past.

```
$upcomingSupportGroups = DB::table('participants')
              ->join('threads', 'participants.thread_id', '=', 'threads.id')
              ->join('support_groups', 'threads.counselling_application_id', '=', 'support_groups.id')
              ->where('participants.user_id', auth()->user()->id)
              ->orWhere('support_groups.counsellor_id', auth()->user()->id)
              ->where('support_groups.event_time', '>=', Carbon\Carbon::now())
              ->groupBy('support_groups.id')
              ->get();
```

Where am i going wrong

Comment: You've probably got an issue your where clauses. Change `->get()` to `->toSql()`, then `dd($upcomingSupportGroups);` and review the generated SQL.

Comment: You're using 2 where's with an orWhere. You'll have to use a closure (`where(function($query){ $query->where()->orWhere();})` or `orWhere(function($query)($query->where()->where();})`) to group your and/or clauses correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have an `orWhere('support_groups.counsellor_id', auth()->user()->id)` you get all rows where the counsellor is the auth user. You want to change the query to:

```
$upcomingSupportGroups = DB::table('participants')
          ->join('threads', 'participants.thread_id', '=', 'threads.id')
          ->join('support_groups', 'threads.counselling_application_id', '=', 'support_groups.id')
          ->where(function($query){
               $query->where('participants.user_id', auth()->user()->id);
               $query->orWhere('support_groups.counsellor_id', auth()->user()->id)
          })
          ->where('support_groups.event_time', '>=', Carbon\Carbon::now())
          ->groupBy('support_groups.id')
          ->get();
```